# Yii1 wrong route when URL contains trailing slash

Tags: php, yii

I have to support one old project which uses Yii1. I get very strange behavior. Pretty URL is configured.

When URL doen't have a trailing slash (e.g. /about or /blog/post/5) everything goes OK (the route is correct and the correct page is displayed). But the same URLs with trailing slash (/about/ or /blog/post/5/) make a wrong route. Disregarding of url I always get the route 'main/index' and index page is displayed (not redirected to, but displayed at all URLs with trailing slash).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and the problem was in nginx config. Yii's pretty URLs require proper config to work. This was strange but the same config worked fine on one server and produced the described behavior on another server.

The problematic config:

```
location ~ ^(.+\.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|swf|mp3|html|eot|woff|ttf|otf|svg|zip|pdf|xml))$
{
  rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1 permanent;
  try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}
```

The working config:

```
location /
{
  index  index.php;
  if (!-e $request_filename)
  {
    rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?r=$1 last;
  }
}
```